# How I do a search with POST in Ember 2 and Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm make a search for a application in Ember 2 which my backend only accept a `POST` for this search, so Im trying send data through customize createRecord, but the behavior is completely different from I'm expected, two points I believe be a problem.

- After several console.log(), I see my actions don't work, even action setted in route.
- Inside Ember Inspector the route for this search haven't a model related

Anyone have a hint about why my route don't have a model related, follow the model declaration for this specific route.

```
model() {
    return {
        data: this.store.findAll('booking'),
        booking: {}
    };
}
```

**PS**: I edited the title, to be more clear about I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use `Ember.RSVP.hash` for that:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        data: this.store.findAll('booking'),
        booking: {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Still don't work. The sendAction not call and the model still hidden in Ember Inspector

Comment: I'm try to access directly from hbs component.

After a change, when I pass the model to the component, work, partially. In first execution, don't work. In a second execution, I see in a first console.log the model object. But don't call my action for the route.

Comment: I do other question and I believe is related with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634755/nothing-handled-the-action-emberjs-2

Comment: you erase the answer for other question, and you was write about the name on sendAction, now works. I like to give the points, fell free to anwser again. Sorry for my cache

Comment: Yes. Continue without send data through actions, but the error asked there was solved and this one too. This application is very painful.